# How to obtain tfid(team foundation id) for azure devops AD group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Could someone provide with the rest api url for finding the tfid for an Azure Devops ad group ?

I am trying to restrict branch permissions for certain AD groups,

"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{}/_api/_security/DisplayPermissions?__v=5&tfid={}&permissionSetId={}&permissionSetToken=repoV2%2F{}%2F{}%2Frefs%5Eheads%5E{}%2F".format(projectID, contributorTfid, nameToken, projectID, repoID, permbranchList[k])

only the contributor tfid here is unknown for me.

Using this rest api endpoint, I have to obtain the permissiontoken

later, using permisisontoken using the json 
branchPermissionbody = {
                "token": "{}".format(permissionToken),
                "merge": True,
                "accessControlEntries": [
                    {
                        "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;{}".format(descriptorIdentifier),
                        "deny": 4,
                        "extendedinfo": {}
                    }
                ]
            }

I am making a post request to post the restriction on the branches

Comment: yes.. that's why I'm asking it here right?

Comment: You've given no indication of what you've tried, where you've looked, or what you're stuck on. You need to provide more details. Please refer to the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok I apologize for that.. new here on stackoverflow. I've updated the question, could you help me now?

Comment: @DanielMann hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get the TeamFoundationId.

1. You can use below REST API to get the groups in your organization.

   https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=5.1-preview.1

Then use Ctrl + F to search the groups in the certain project. The originid is the TeamFoundationId. More details information about this REST API, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1.

2. Also you can use F12 to manual catch the TeamFoundationId. Log in to Project settings-> Repositories, then click F12 to open the Network console. Clear sessions then change the group permission. You can get the TeamFoundationId in the Request body or Response body.
   [image]